# How is the preconditioned conjugate gradient algorithm related to the steepest descent method?

Tags: matrices

[image: Preconditioned Conjugate Gradient Algorithm]

There is a method to greatly simplify the preconditioned conjugate method into the steepest descent method, also known as gradient descent. I'm aware that the gradient is equal to $$2A^t(A\vec{x} - \vec{b})$$

But I don't know how to apply this.

Comment: You can get the (preconditioned) steepest descent method by replacing $d\Leftarrow s+\beta d$ with $d\Leftarrow s$ (or simply by using the preconditioned residual $s$ instead of the direction vector $d$); of course, you can erase the lines required to compute $d$, namely you don't need $\beta$ and $\delta_{old}$.

Comment: However, note that, although the resulting method is "greatly" simpler, it is also usually [*greatly* worse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655306/conjugate-gradient-method-and-sparse-systems/658644#658644) than PCG.

Comment: What exactly is your question?